# Intersection of subgroups is a subgroup: What if collection of subsets is empty?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, logic

> Theorem: The intersection of **any arbitrary collection** of subgroups of a group is again a subgroup.

http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_of_subgroups_is_subgroup

I don't understand the comment at this link: "If the collection  is empty, the intersection is defined to be the whole group. In this case, the intersection is clearly a subgroup."

Should the theorem not be for "any arbitrary **non-empty** collection of subgroups?" (Edit: Relatively easy to formally prove using ordinary logic and set theory.)

Comment: If "the intersection is **defined** to be the whole group" then what actually is the problem?

Comment: It seems to me to be a very odd definition.

Comment: @DanChristensen And odd it is. In general. the intersection $\bigcap_{i\in I}X_i$ of a familiy of sets is defined (is a set) only if $I$ is nonempty. For the case of empty $I$ one *would* have to take the "universal set" as result, which makes no sense. However, in the *context* of subgroups of a specific group $G$, we may well take $G$ itself as this universal set.

Comment: @DanChristensen I think in set theory if the universal set is $U,$ an empty intersection is always $U.$

Comment: @coffeemath In set theory, the universal set can be shown not to exist. Every set must exclude something.

Comment: @DanChristensen But I was only using a universal set in the sense of a chosen specific set (for a particular context in using set theory) which in that context will be taken to have in it all the elements under consideration. This is like the use of it in statements like: Given a property P and a set $S$ there is a collection of elements A in S for which P(x) holds [ x in S] iff x in A. This is one of the usual things done to avoid Russell's paradox.

Comment: The intersection is the product in the category of sets. So the intersection of an empty collection is the limit of the functor $F:\varphi\rightarrow \operatorname{Set},$ and looking closely at the corresponding universal property, it would then become natural to define the intersection as the whole group. BTW, this view also provides a short proof of the theorem: subgroups are kernels, so the intersection of kernels is equal to the kernel of the intersection, as the limit is continuous... Just some categorical gibberish. :P

Comment: @awllower Would these theorems you mention not be provable without this notion? It all seems a bit dodgy to me. I don't remember such esoteric considerations when I took an introductory course in group theory many years ago.

Comment: @DanChristensen Do you mean can we prove an intersection of subgroups is a subgroup without the use of continuous functors, etc. ? If so, then of course we can, and I just pointed out some viewpoints here. And as to the validity, these categorical tools are indeed independent of the algebraic notions here, at least IMHO.

Comment: @awllower Would a similar theorem on a non-empty collection of subgroups be much less useful? It would certainly be easier to prove using ordinary set theory.

Comment: Indeed, but we can use the same technique to prove similar theorems in other settings, all at once. Also, I am not implying the superiority of the categorical notions; I just point this view out, not to judge its usefulness or something. And I think which notion to adapt is a simple matter of taste. Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's like the empty product or the empty sum.

$$\prod_{x\in\emptyset}x=1$$
$$\sum_{x\in\emptyset}x=0$$
$$\bigcap_{x\in\emptyset}x=G$$
and through similar reasoning one would get
$$\bigcup_{x\in\emptyset}x=\emptyset$$
as the operation on the empty set is always the neutral element of that operation. The reason is such that you can say "any collection" rather than adding lots and lots of additional words such as "non-empty" etc, it's neater if we include all possibilities.

Comment: So is $\bigcap \emptyset$ equal to $\Bbb{Z}$ or $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: Depends on what the universe is

Comment: So you should explain in your answer that by an **abuse of notation** the meaning of formulas like $\bigcap\emptyset$ is dependent on implicit contextual information.

Answer (score 2):

For a collection $C$ of subsets of a set $S,$ the intersection of $C$ is the set of elements of $S$ which belong to each element of $C.$ So if $C$ is empty, it would be the collection of $x$ such that, for each set $E$ in $C,$ we have $x \in E.$ Since there are no such sets $E,$ one can say that IF $E \in C$ THEN $x \in E,$ because the part just after the IF is always false, and a false proposition implies *any* proposition. So we do indeed get all of $S$ being the intersection here.

Comment: For $n\in\Bbb Z$ let $A_n=n\Bbb Z$. What is $\bigcap{i\in I}A_i$ if we let $I=\{2,3\}$ - that'ts easy. What is it if $I=\emptyset$? Plea don't say that it is $\Bbb Z$. For I forgot to tell you that I consider $n\Bbb Z$ to be subsets of $\Bbb Q[\sqrt 2]$ ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The definition which leads to empty intersections being $U$ is predicated on the universal set $U$ being chosen at the outset. So if one changes the universal set that changes the resulting value of an empty intersection.